# multiple audio files simultaneously iphone

Tags: iphone, audio, avaudioplayer

Is it possible to play multiple audio files simultaneously.the number of audio file depends on the web response.
For example if there are tree audio files then view show tree players and user can play two audio files and stop them separately/one by one not at the same time.

Can i do this using AVAudioPlayer ?
Please give me your suggestion

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I have played 2 Videos using AVAudioPlayer. So I guess it will do the same for audio files.
I guess you can play to file simultaneously.

But After playing Video 3-4 times player stop playing any video no matter what you do. That was the known bug in iOS 4.